# Failure has occurred loading type after CU2 for BizTalk 2013R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

After installing CU2 in BizTalk 2013R2 we got the following error

> Failure has occurred loading type

It looks like it is occurring in the map on the port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an explanation of the issue in this blog [BizTalk 2013 R2 CU2 – Failure has occurred while loading a type](http://www.bizzybloggers.com/2016/01/biztalk-2013-r2-cu2-failure-has-occurred-while-loading-a-type/) where apparently they have introduced a new Use XSLT transform attribute in the map, grid properties under Standalone.
Setting this attribute and redeploying fixes it, but that may be too much risk for a Production environment,

It has been raised with Microsoft, and hopefully will get released as a hot fix.

For now, if you can do without CU2 I would hold off on applying CU2 until it is fixed or the hotfix is available.

**UPDATE**: Microsoft released a new CU2-package with a hotfix for the problem. You can download it at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3119352