# BizTalk 2013 R2 CU2 not installing properly

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to install the CU2 found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3119352) for BizTalk 2013 R2. After installing the patch (installer reports installation successful) BizTalk's version remains the same. As per the patch list the version is supposed to be 3.11.237.2, yet in the registry the version is still showing 3.11.158.0. I looked in the list of installed updates under Control Panel, and I do not see the patch for Biztalk 2013 R2 listed; however, I do see the patch showing up for Biztalk 2013 R2 Accelerator for HL7 and Biztalk Adapter Pack (x64).

[image: Installed Patches Screen Cap]

When I try to run the patch installer again, I get this error: "An unexpected internal error has occurred."

Any ideas as to how I can confirm if the patch is really successfully applied or how to troubleshoot the installer error?

Comment: Check for the BizTalk CU2 under UDDI, that's where the first* version of CU2 ended up.   * Note: There was an earlier version of CU2 that broke all maps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664270/failure-has-occurred-loading-type-after-cu2-for-biztalk-2013r2

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf! I installed the patched CU2, the one with the map fix in place. is that also suppose to go under UDDI? Is UDDI applicable to Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: UDDI is deprecated, so I doubt that it should go there, but that is where it ended up last time.  I just double checked an environment we had patched, and it ended up under the Adapter Pack as you stated in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the registry version number does not change so you can't verify it that way.

To verify that it has installed open up Add/Remove programs, click View installed updates and look for the BizTalk CU2 under Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack

[image]

The other place you can check is the version numbers of the DLLs that are matches

[image]
[image]

**Update**: [CU3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3158677) is now available that has some fixes related to installation issues.